# How to get the list of methods of a ruby script with their parameters in JRuby from Java

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I know how to get the list of method names from a Ruby script from Java in JRuby. For example with this Java code:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
container.setCompileMode(CompileMode.JIT);
Object receiver = container.runScriptlet(PathType.CLASSPATH, new File(<Ruby script path>);
String[] names = (String[]) container.runScriptlet("require 'java'; String.instance_methods.to_java :string");
```

But I would like to be able to have not only the names of the methods, but also their full signature. How is it possible to do that in JRuby?

Comment: There's no way of getting all methods defined in Ruby. [Solargraph](https://github.com/castwide/solargraph) can give you an approximation, but enumerating them all is impossible, they can be created at any time by code you may not have run.

Comment: As @tadman said, you can't get them all. Ruby lets us create classes and methods on the fly so unless something is running the code and knows how to exercise every method it won't find them. Debugging Rails can be "interesting" that way.

Comment: @theTinMan It's worse than that. Maybe executing one method precludes executing another, each time the method's run it produces different results, or that the method can be called an infinite number of ways with an infinite number of possible side-effects.

Comment: Oh, I knew that Ruby was a dynamic language, but your answer makes perfect sense.!!

Comment: Tools like New Relic accomplish this by monitoring all method calls and reporting on them, but of course if the method isn't called the method isn't reported.